# How to merge/stack observations by date in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have a data frame like

```
date             X1 X2 X3
4/16/2019 0:00   1  2  3
4/16/2019 7:00   1  2  3
4/172019 0:00    1  2  3
4/17/2019 7:00   1  2  3
```

I would like to get

```
date        time     X1      X2      X3
4/16/2019   c(0,7)   c(1,1)  c(2,2)  c(3,3)
4/17/2019   c(0,7)   c(1,1)  c(2,2)  c(3,3)
```

where `X1` is a list and `X1[[1]]` is a vector, that is `c(1,1)`.

Is there an efficient way to achieve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the 'date' into 'date', 'time' columns at the space (`\\s+`), grouped by 'date', then `summarise` `across` all the columns by wrapping them in a `list`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%   
   separate(date, into = c('date', 'time'), sep = '\\s+') %>%
   mutate(time = as.numeric(str_replace(time, ":", ".")) %>%
   group_by(date) %>%
   summarise(across(everything(), ~ list(.)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  date      time      X1        X2        X3       
  <chr>     <list>    <list>    <list>    <list>   
1 4/16/2019 <dbl [2]> <int [2]> <int [2]> <int [2]>
2 4/17/2019 <dbl [2]> <int [2]> <int [2]> <int [2]>
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(date = c("4/16/2019 0:00", "4/16/2019 7:00", 
"4/17/2019 0:00", 
"4/17/2019 7:00"), X1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), X2 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), X3 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: ok! And could you help me transform each component of the list `time` to a numerical vector, i.e `time[[1]] = c(0,7)`. I know this is an inappropriate asking (I am a mathematical statistics student). I failed through `as.numeric(df1$time[[1]])`. Thank you!

Comment: @HJLiang I used `parse_number` as in the update.  Do you have minutes as well.  In that case what would be the output i.e. `"07:43"` etc?

Comment: You are more thoughtful! In my dataset, every individual is repeatedly observed on the hour. So if the data has minutes as well, maybe I will use decimals to record it, i.e. `7.43` .

Comment: @HJLiang in that case, just replace the `:` with `.` and use `as.numeric` as in the update

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way how you could do it:
Logic:

1. separate date and time column (other then with `separate`, as already provided by akrun)
2. group
3. summarise with `across` using `list` and `lambda paste` (notice the `.names` argument in `summarise`
4. use again `across` and `lambda paste0`

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
df %>% 
  mutate(date = mdy_hm(date)) %>% 
  mutate(time = parse_number(sprintf("%02d", hour(date))), .before=2,
         date = as.Date(ymd_hms(date))) %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), list(~paste(.,collapse=",")), .names="{col}")) %>% 
  mutate(across(-date, ~paste0("c(",.,")")))
```

```
  date       time   X1     X2     X3    
  <date>     <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1 2019-04-16 c(0,7) c(1,1) c(2,2) c(3,3)
2 2019-04-17 c(0,7) c(1,1) c(2,2) c(3,3)
```